# Lombok @Getter and copies of Collections

Tags: java, collections, lombok

Using `@Getter` on a `List` field works fine, but on attempting to upgrade to Java 8 I encounter `ConcurrentModificationException`s because the getter generated by Lombok does not perform a copy of the field, which is essential should you wish to prevent external modification of the instance's state.

Any ideas how I can get Lombok to copy the `Collection` on getters, or am I restricted to writing my own?

Comment: A getter should not copy, it should wrap in `Collections.unmodifiableList`. The caller should make a copy if it would like a mutable collection for its own use. This makes the code cleaner, and is a convention that avoids bugs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [@Getter and @Setter](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) documentation:

> You can annotate any field with @Getter and/or @Setter, to let lombok generate the default getter/setter automatically.
>   A default getter simply returns the field, and is named getFoo if the field is called foo (or isFoo if the field's type is boolean). A default setter is named setFoo if the field is called foo, returns void, and takes 1 parameter of the same type as the field. It simply sets the field to this value.

Since you want more functionality then the default getter you'll have to write your own.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but the answer nonetheless :'(

Comment: There is no way to do this with some lombok annotation/config right ?

Comment: And an even more recent discussion about this: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1504

Comment: It was discussed (and rejected) by Lombok [here](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1504) and yet there's also an opened issue [here](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3241). Feel free to thumbs up...